# How to make a Chef custom resource execute on every chef run

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a custom Chef resource that starts a background job. It has `:start`, `:stop` and `:reset` actions.

There is another resource that notifies `:reset` to my custom one when it is updated.

The main problem I have is that on each `chef-client` run the status of the resource returns:

```
custom_resource[resource-name] action start (up to date)
custom_resource[resource-name] action reset (up to date)
```

This behavior from Chef is the one I expect but not the one I need. My resource must be run on each `chef-client` run like the resource `execute` does. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You'll have to play with the state of your resource for that, without it's code it's hard to tell how to tweak it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does run every time by default, but unless you call `new_resource.updated_by_last_action(true)` or a similar API Chef shows "up to date" because the resource hasn't said it updated anything on the system.

Comment: This is no longer the suggested method in chef11.x/12.x

Answer (score 0):

The answer described [here](https://gist.github.com/lamont-granquist/8cda474d6a31fadd3bb3b47a66b0ae78) is the recommended way in Chef 11.x/12.x.

Add the below in your custom resource file.

```
def whyrun_supported?
  true
end
```